# How do I find solutions for deprecated code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, quicktime, qtkit

I'm new to Mac programming. When I open sample projects, I often get 'deprecated' code warnings during a build. I'd like to fix these and get a clean build using XCode 4.

When Apple deprecates something, how do I find out why it was deprecated?

More importantly, how do I find out what is the 'new' correct way to implement the deprecated task?

For example, I'm seeing deprecation warnings for: QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification, writeWithBackupToFile, documentForFileName, shouldCreateUI, setShowPanels, QTMovieCurrentSizeAttribute, and many others.

Answer (score 5):

Look up the method in the documentation - they show the deprecated methods and tell you what the preferred methods are.

For example `writeWithBackupToFile` is clearly marked as deprecated and shows that `writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error:` should be used instead.

Same with `shouldCreateUI` which shows that either `openUntitledDocumentAndDisplay:error:` or `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:error:` should be used instead.

Also, read the other methods in the documentation - you'll find things that do what you need. For example you list `QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification` as being deprecated (in QuickTime 7.6.3). Right above it in the documentation you can see `QTMovieNaturalSizeDidChangeNotification` which has been available since QuickTime 7.6.3). Use that instead.

Comment: +1 and @Brian: reading the "Release Notes" can also be very helpful, if a bit on the dry side.

Comment: @Abizem I've been researching and testing some more. Thanks, all. I've successfully cleaned away half my depreciation warnings. Also, found that QTMovieNaturalSizeDidChangeNotification is not a replacement for QTMovieSizeDidChangeNotification. Likewise QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute is not a replacement for QTMovieCurrentSizeAttribute. Natural Size refers to the QTMovie's native resolution, while Current Size refer to the resolution at which a QTMovie is being displayed (this may also be the resolution to which the movie is being decoded, which can resize from native). Any ideas finding new way?

Comment: I'm not a QuickTime programmer - I was just showing you a way of dealing with deprecated functions. Have you tried asking on the Apple Developer forums, or the QuickTime API mailing list?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You've solved many of my problems! How do I get onto the QuickTime API mailing list? I had tried to find a list of relevant Apple Dev mailing lists, but I appear to be google-challenged. ^_^ Do you know a link to them?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the deprecated things in the documentation. Usually, there's a note that suggests what to use instead.

For example, the documentation for `writeWithBackupToFile:ofType:saveOperation:` says:

> This method is called by action methods to save document contents to a file. (**Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.4. Use writeSafelyToURL:ofType:forSaveOperation:error: instead.**)

Comment: Thank you. I followed your lead. To anyone else watching this, I found great sample code for this in the QTMetadataEditor, from the Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 0):

Search the documentation for that method/function/constant.  It should list there what to use instead, or at least bring up a class that obviously has other methods that do something similar.